# git always fails to authenticate

Tags: git, github

So, every while, when I'm not doing anything on git, it kicks me out. Then, when I try to push anything to the repo, I get:

`remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/username/repo/'`

Then I have to go through all kind of commands I find on internet to get back to be authenticated. And one procedure not always works, so every time I have to try "stuff" until mr. git decides to let me in again.

My question is, is there any standard workflow for this situation?

My config file is fine, the repository origin is set up correctly. I have removed and origin and set it back. Basically I have done everything from other posts, and I am still getting the error.

This happened once (that I was not able to resolve), and I just gave up, deleted .git folder and did `git init` again. Wouldn't it be super easy to have `git login`?

Since I am starting to really hate git, I am thinking in using other version control system (if there is no simple solution for this issue). For what I am doing (which is just pushing and pulling couple of files per day)...

Comment: Did you read [Caching your GitHub password in Git](https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/) or try using SSH?

Comment: Why does github's authentication policy make you hate git? You're having a problem with a particular hosting site, not the SCM tool itself.

Comment: you could also try making your remote url be something like the following: `https://<username>@github.com/username/repo`  that way if the caching fails, it will just ask for your password and you can keep on moving. Going to SSH is the real solution that makes working w/ git repos hosted elseware very simple

Comment: I guess you are using [two](https://help.github.com/articles/github-terms-of-service/#b-account-terms) GitHub accounts at the same time, then [Git Credential](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials) suffers.

Comment: @Useless Because git should be more user friendly, precisely with github, which is not. I don't like wasting my time, and I definitely don't want to become an expert with git (at this point of my life) for the user I give to it. So, mercurial is the next toy to try.

Comment: This isn't a criticism (I have no idea what other constraints you're working with) but IME many developers think SCM should be easy, refuse to spend effort learning it well, and it causes lots of avoidable problems. If you switch to Mercurial and also drop that at the first difficulty, you'll have two tools you can use badly rather than one you can use well.

Comment: I definitely don't give up at the first difficulty. But I do expect helper tools to not bother.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the issue was that there were two accounts, as Geno Chen suggested. Looks like a quickstart I did on Google Cloud Platform (where I have a different account), had a gcloud.sh file for credentials, and it was messing with my regular account.

I had removed everything though from the command line, by doing `git config --global --unset credential.helper` and it seem to not had worked.

I manually edited `.gitconfig` file and removed the lines where the helper, under credentials was not removed. It's strange though. After running the command mentioned above to remove credential helpers, my config file still had these lines:

```
[credential]
    helper = credential-gcloud.sh
```

Anyways, now it works, I still don't like git, and now I have one more technique to resolve this same issue.